# Capturing key input from events device and mapping it (toggle TouchPad key is unmapped)

Tags: kernel, drivers, input, events

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad Yoga 13 with Ubuntu 13.10 Installed. The device has a "Toggle TouchPad" button on the keyboard (<kbd>F5</kbd>). The keyboard's <kbd>F*</kbd> buttons are reversed (so to get <kbd>F5</kbd>, I need to press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>, and <kbd>F5</kbd> is actually the toggle key).

I've found out that the button is actually read by the keyboard (rather than the TouchPad like certain devices), which is at `/dev/input/event3`. So using `sudo input-events 3` I was able to figure out that the button sends the scan code 190:

Output of `sudo lsinput`:

```
/dev/input/event3
   bustype : BUS_I8042
   vendor  : 0x1
   product : 0x1
   version : 43907
   name    : "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
   phys    : "isa0060/serio0/input0"
   bits ev : EV_SYN EV_KEY EV_MSC EV_LED EV_REP
```

Output of `sudo input-events 3`:

```
23:13:03.849392: EV_MSC MSC_SCAN 190
23:13:03.849392: EV_SYN code=0 value=0
23:13:03.855413: EV_MSC MSC_SCAN 190
23:13:03.855413: EV_SYN code=0 value=0
```

No other programs (such as `xev`) seem to be able to read it except for `input-events`. Is there any way to map this button to make it toggle the TouchPad on my laptop? If so, how can I do so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it turns out the kernel did pick it up, but kept complaining that it's not recognised.

**For anyone else having this issue, or wants to map a key that's not read by the OS, read on.**

Open a terminal and run `dmesg | grep -A 1 -i setkeycodes`. This will give you multiple entries like this:

```
[    9.307463] atkbd serio0: Unknown key pressed (translated set 2, code 0xbe on isa0060/serio0).
[    9.307476] atkbd serio0: Use 'setkeycodes e03e <keycode>' to make it known.
```

What we are interested is the hexadecimal value after "setkeycodes", in this case this is `e03e`. If you have multiple of these, you can run `tail -f /var/log/kern.log`. Once you've done so, you can tap the button you're looking for, and this will give you a the same line as above, and again, we only need the hexadecimal value. Make a note of this.

Now run `xmodmap -pke | less` and find the appropriate mapping. In my case, I needed to map this to toggle my touch pad, which means I was interested in the following line:

```
keycode 199 = XF86TouchpadToggle NoSymbol XF86TouchpadToggle
```

If you can't find whatever you're interested in, read @Gilles answer too, as you can define custom mappings too, then read on (if the kernel reads it, you won't need to add it to xorg.conf.d)

Now I ran the following command: `sudo setkeycodes [hexadecimal] [keycode]`, so in my case that became: `setkeycodes e03e 199`.

Now you can use the following line to test if it worked and/or you have the correct mapping:

```
xev | grep -A2 --line-buffered '^KeyRelease' | sed -n '/keycode /s/^.*keycode \([0-9]*\).* (.*, \(.*\)).*$/\1 \2/p'
```

When you run this command, you need to focus on the newly opened window (`xev`) and check the console output. In my case it read as following:

```
207 NoSymbol
```

This was obviously wrong, as I requested keycode `199`, so it's mapped to `XF86TouchpadToggle`. I checked `xmodmap -pke` again, and noticed that `keycode 207` is actually mapped to `NoSymbol`, and I noticed that there was an offset difference of 8, so I tried the `setkeycodes` command again, but the key is mapped to `keycode 191`.

```
sudo setkeycodes e03e 191
```

This worked perfectly.

EDIT -- the solution I provided to have to working on start up does not. I will figure this out tomorrow and update this answer. For now I suppose you can run this on start up manually.

Comment: how to make it permanent in the nice way? (i.e. after reset/boot-up)

Answer (score 4):

From the looks of it, the device is a keyboard (recognized in software as separate from the “core” keyboard) but the X server isn't listening to it.

Try [adding an Input section under `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Input). That is, create a directory `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` if it doesn't already exist, and create a file `extra-keyboard-buttons` in that directory containing

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "extra-keyboard-buttons"
    Driver "kbd"
    MatchProduct "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
EndSection
```

I'm not sure about that `MatchProduct` line; if it doesn't work, try fiddling with the [`MatchXXX` directives](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man5/xorg.conf.5.xhtml#heading9).

Once this file is set up correctly, when you start the X server, it should process events from this keyboard, and you should see events in `xev` and elsewhere. Note the keycode (I'm not sure if the X11 keycode will be the same as the hardware keycode in this case) and associate a keysym to it. You can do it via a file called `.Xmodmap` in your home directory containing

```
keycode 190 = XF86_Launch5
```

You can now [define keyboard shortcuts](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts) using these keys.

To toggle the touchpad, use the command [`xinput`](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/xinput.1.xhtml). Run `xinput list` to see what input devices are available and note the name of your touchpad (I'll call it `Touchpad` below). Run `xinput list-props Touchpad` to list its properties; one of them should be called “Device Enabled” with a number next to it (e.g. 135). The following script will toggle the touchpad:

```
#!/bin/sh
device_name='Touchpad'
property=135
flipped_state=$(xinput list-props "$device_name" |
                awk "/\\($property\\)/ {print 1 - \$NF}")
xinput set-prop "$device_name" "$property" "$flipped_state"
```

Save this in a file `~/bin/toggle-touchpad` and make it executable (`chmod +x ~/bin/toggle-touchpad`). To bind it to a key, install [xbindkeys](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xbindkeys) and configure it to run your script by putting the following lines in `~/.xbindkeysrc`:

```
"toggle-touchpad"
  XF86_Launch5
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This unfortunately didn't work. I got it working though, so feel free to have a look at my own answer! :)